# Dealing With Multiple Flatlists on the same Screen

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, react-native-flatlist

Please help my deal with unnecessary re-renders when having two flatlists on the same screen

My screen requires two flatlists-

1. For **HOSTS**
2. For **QUEUE**

When the component mounts, I get data from the api call like this-

```
{
  "hosts": [{"id":"1", "name":"kyouma"},...],
  "queue": [{"id":"99", "name":"eren"},...]
}
```

Now what I do is I store my *hosts* and *queue* separately in my redux store like this-

```
this.props.dispatch({
        type: GET_ROOM_HOSTS,
        payload: info['hosts']
      })

this.props.dispatch({
        type: GET_ROOM_QUEUE,
        payload: info['queue']
      })
```

where **info** is the object received from the api call as shown above. Now I **mapStateToProps** these two from the redux store to the default screen component such that-

1. `this.props.roomQueue` is for *queue* and
2. `this.props.roomHosts` is for *hosts*

My **FlatList's** are like this-

```
<FlatList
   data={this.props.roomQueue}
   horizontal={true}
   keyExtractor = {item => item.id}
   renderItem({item} => {
    return(
        <customComponent (with suitable props) ..../>
        )
    })
/>
```

```
<FlatList
   data={this.props.roomHosts}
   numColumns={3}
   keyExtractor = {item => item.id}
   renderItem({item} => {
    return(
        <customComponent (with suitable props) ..../>
        )
    })
/>
```

**PLEASE NOTE** that both the *FlatList's* are present in the same Component (React.Component) of the screen and are displayed at different parts of the screen(queue at bottom of the screen and hosts at the top of the screen). Also *queue* and *hosts* are independent of each other. Screen looks like this[image]

My problem is that even if there is a change in `this.props.roomQueue`, the **FlatList** having its `data={this.props.roomHosts}` get's re-rendered.

How do i prevent this re-render to ensure that only if the *FlatList's* corresponding data changes, then only will it re-render, otherwise it won't. Do I have to change the way I store *queue* and *hosts*? or is there something else?

Comment: How do you render your items in your 2 flatlists ?

Comment: @ViktorJovanovic please check the updated question. My FlatList's are standard.

Comment: Actually, it seems right what you're doing.
Does your "CustomComponent" component extend from PureComponent? If you don't, I really think it can help you to resolve your problem in combination with immerJS if your objects "QueueRoom" and "HostRoom" have more than 1 level of depth. (https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactpurecomponent)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with using only one flatlist. Merge your both array's into one and show results from one list.. you can spare them in ui with a type.

This is a genuine procedure of what developers do, cz rendering 2 list in same page and same direction is accually no mean. Your query is valid.

Comment: I can't do that because both the data are independent of each other, and the Flatlists are displayed at different parts of the screen

Comment: You have to customise so that you can objectify different items..like suppose you have HOSTS QUEUE combine in one array.. you can push a key as type to every objects to differentiate them

Comment: that would again mean re-renders even if one out of hosts or queue changes

Answer (score 1):

You can add List ListFooterComponent and it will automatically do this for you

```
<FlatList
      contentContainerStyle={{
        width: WINDOW_WIDTH,
        paddingVertical:WINDOW_WIDTH*0.2,
        marginLeft:10
      }}
      ListFooterComponent={()=> returnYourViewDesignHere()}
      columnWrapperStyle={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: "space-around" }}
      keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
      onEndReached={() => getPaginationData()}
      onEndReachedThreshold={0.0001}
      numColumns={3}
      showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
      data={allShows}
      renderItem={({ item, index }) => {
        return (
          <TouchableWithoutFeedback
            key={item.index + Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000)}
            onPress={() =>
              props.navigation.navigate(
                item.type == "movie" ? "MovieDetailScreen" : "SeasonDetail",
                {
                  data: item,
                  object: {
                    id: item.id,
                  },
                }
              )
            }
          >
            <View style={styles.boxContainer}>
              <View style={styles.imageBackground}>
                <Text style={styles.backgroundText}>KEIN</Text>
                <Text
                  style={[styles.backgroundText, { color: COLOR.primary }]}
                >
                  POSTER
                </Text>
              </View>
              <Image
                source={{
                  uri: item.coverUrl ? item.coverUrl : item.coverPath,
                }}
                style={styles.imageBox}
                resizeMode={"stretch"}
              />
              <Text
                numberOfLines={2}
                ellipsizeMode={"tail"}
                style={styles.text}
              >
                {item.showTitle ? item.showTitle : item.title}
              </Text>
              {userWatchedList.some((uwl) => uwl.id == item.id) ? (
                <TouchableWithoutFeedback
                  onPress={() =>
                    isloggedIn
                      ? removeFromUserWatchList(item)
                      : handleModalVisibility()
                  }
                >
                  <Image
                    source={WATCHLIST_CHECKED}
                    style={{
                      width: 25,
                      height: 25,
                      position: "absolute",
                      right: 5,
                      top: 5,
                    }}
                  />
                </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
              ) : (
                <TouchableWithoutFeedback
                  onPress={() =>
                    isloggedIn
                      ? addToUserWatchList(item)
                      : handleModalVisibility()
                  }
                >
                  <Image
                    source={CIRCLE_UNCHECKED}
                    style={{
                      width: 25,
                      height: 25,
                      position: "absolute",
                      right: 5,
                      top: 5,
                    }}
                  />
                </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
              )}
            </View>
          </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
        );
      }}
    />
```